# Property missing in state but is only a prop with flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, flowtype

```
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
  number: number,
}

type State = {

}

class Other extends React.Component <State, Props> {
  render() {
    const { number } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {number}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

//

```
import * as React from 'react';
type Props = {

}

type State = {
  number: number,
  cards: Array<{suit: string} | {rank: number}>,
}

class Example extends React.Component <Props, State>{
     <Other
       number={this.state.number}
     />
}
```

so, I'm getting this weird error with flow after integrating with React. My `Example` component passes `number` state down as a prop to `Other`. and in `Other` I have told it that `number` is a prop that should be of type number. however, it complains and says that it should be in state??

I get it should be state in the original component but why is it wanting it to be state in the new component? surely declaring it in state doesn't make sense as it's just a read-only prop that I want to render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you mixed up the type declarations on your `Other` component. The first parameter should be the props interface, the second should be state. In your original example you are passing `State` as the declaration for the props, and conversely `Props` as the definition for the state. That's why you'll get the error that `Other` expects the value to be in state instead of props.

Current: 
`class Other extends React.Component <State, Props>`

Should Be: `class Other extends React.Component <Props, State>`

Comment: Cheers, glad I could help. If that solves your problem I'd appreciate it if you could mark my answer as the accepted one :)